# How to shadow a static variable in a local scope, while still have access to static variable

Tags: c#

Given the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyLogger.ILog Log = MyLogger.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

    private void DoSomethingLogged()
    {
        var Log = MyLogger.LogManager.GetLogger(MyClass.Log.Name+"::"+nameof(DoSomethingLogged));

        Log.Info("method called");
    }
}
```

when using `var Log = ...` in DoSomething, there's does not seem to be a way to access the static variable `MyClass::Log`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't `MyClass.Log` work? Also, what's the reason behind your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the static field by qualifying it with the class name

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyLogger.ILog Log = MyLogger.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

    private void DoSomethingLogged()
    {
        var Log = MyLogger.LogManager.GetLogger(MyClass.Log.Name+"::"+nameof(DoSomethingLogged));
        var localLog = Log;
        var staticLog = MyClass.Log;

        Log.Info("method called");
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see, the code already has `MyClass.Log.Name`, so it is quite obvious that's not the OP's own code so this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ah, good catch! Didn't see that. It does answer the question asked, though I'll grant you the OP may be asking the wrong question.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing that worries me, what's the actual question here? "what does this code do?"? (you would have seen an answer from me if the underlying question was clear enough, that's why I just left a comment instead)